# How to use insert with replace in JavaScript using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to learn to use $$, $&, $`,$',$n in my replace function. I am looking for some examples like this:

```js
var re = /(\w+)\s(\w+)/;
var str = "mango apple banana orange";
var newstr = str.replace(re, "$2 $1");
console.log(newstr);//outputs apple mango banana orange, (how does it do this?)
```

Can anyone provide me with some examples and explanation on the use of each of these? I found out about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and trying to understand.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be *"hacking"* for your question. But since you just want to know how it works, I think it's still be a good practise:

```js
var re = /(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\w+)/;
var str = "mango apple banana orange";
var newstr = str.replace(re, "$2 $1 $3 $4");
console.log(newstr);//outputs apple mango banana orange, (how does it do this?)
```

- `\w`: Matches alphabet character and numeric (a-z, A-Z and 0-9).
- `\w+`: Matches with this pattern one or more times.
- `(\w+)`: Wrap this pattern in a group.
- `\s`: Matches space

The first pattern `(\w+)` matches `mango`, the second pattern matches `apple`, same to the others...

Then, in the output, if you want to use the matched result inside each group, you can use:

```
"$2 $1 $3 $4"
```

- `$2`: prints the matched result in group 2
- `$1`: prints the matched result in group 1
- `$3`: prints the matched result in group 3
- `$4`: prints the matched result in group 4

---

`$$` is used to insert a `$` character to the result:

```js
console.log('abc'.replace(/(a)(b)(c)/, '$1 $$ $2'));
```

In this example, we split `abc` to 3 groups. Group 1 contains `a`, group 2 contains `b`, group 3 contains `c`. Then, we replace 3 groups with group 1 value + `$` character + group 2 value.

---

`` $` `` is used to insert a character which is getting before the matched string

```js
console.log('abc'.replace(/b/, '$`'));
```

It matches `b` character, then getting `a` character to replace with `b`

---

`$'` is used to insert a character which is getting after the matched string

```js
console.log('abc'.replace(/b/, "$'"));
```

It matches `b` character, then getting `c` character to replace with `b`

---

`$&` is used to insert the matched string. If not matched, it returns the default string.

```js
console.log('abc'.replace(/(b)/, '$1 $&'));
console.log('abc'.replace(/x/, '$&'));
```

---

The way to use `$n` is as same as the way to use `$1` `$2` `$3` and `$4` above. We replace `n` with `1` `2` `3` `4`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you also give some examples using $$, $&, $`,$',$n?

Comment: Thank you. This makes more sense now.